# Как создать "сырой" UDP сокет?

Tags: php, сокет, сокеты

Пытаюсь создать сырой UDP сокет, но выдает ошибку 10013.

```
Warning: socket_create(): Unable to create socket [10013]: 

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, SOL_UDP);
```

Comment: для сокета нужен сервер, по id:port сервер запущен?

Comment: "Сырые" сокеты только из под root/admin создаются, вероятнее всего вы делаете это из под веб-сервера у которого недостаточно прав

Comment: @RTK спасибо, а как создать сырой UDP сокет, который использует датаграммы?